# Add "IgnoreCase" and "Contains" to Django-Filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Is there a way that i can add Ignore-Case and Contains functionalities to Django-Filter ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's clearly written there in the [django-filter documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#declaring-filters) of course.

You just need to do something like that:

```py
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    manufacturer__name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

The `icontains` lookup means case-insensitive and contains

Comment: Listed documentation link was broken for me but I did find something in the FAQ section: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tips.html?highlight=icontains#missing-lookup-expr-for-text-search-filters

and additional documentation: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/settings.html?highlight=icontains

I personally did not find the documentation to be "clear" enough, but with better Google-ing I was able to find something more concrete: https://www.w3schools.com/django/ref_lookups_icontains.php

Comment: @TimD Fixed the link